# 120dpi screws up quick report printing

Tags: delphi, dpi, quickreports

I have several reports in my application that are using quickreports. When I print them on a machine that has it's dpi setting at 96 they print correctly. If I change the dpi setting on the machine to 120 and print again the report layout expands off the page, all the elements start at the same position as the 96 dpi setting but the fonts enlarge an run off the page. I can't seem to figure out how to make it always print as if the setting were 96 dpi.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so now all I can say is the devil was in the details. There is no issue specifically with quick reports and 120 dpi. The issue was with a PDF export component I was using that does not get the DPI settings from the form during runtime. So sense the exporter was stuck in 96 dpi, even though the form was in 120 dpi, I would get skewed reports. The fix is to set the dpi for the exporter in runtime.